# Why is setInterval not working when trying to make a countdown

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, replit

I am trying to create a counter in javascript and I was using setInterval to change the timer every millisecond but it doesn't change the timer. The timer is the same unless I reload the page.
My code:
 HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="final"> <b id="year"></b>:<b id="month"></b>:<b id="days"></b>:<b id="minutes"></b>:<b id="seconds"></b>:<b id="milli"></b></h1>
    <h1 id="end" hidden>Counter is done</h1>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My js:

```js
year = document.getElementById("year")
month = document.getElementById("month")
days = document.getElementById("days")
milli = document.getElementById("milli")
minutes = document.getElementById("minutes")
seconds = document.getElementById("seconds")
currentDate = new Date()
snapDay = new Date("Nov 25, 2019 0:0:0")
it = setInterval(function(){
  if(currentDate.getMinutes() == snapDay.getMinutes() && currentDate.getDate() == snapDay.getDate() && snapDay.getFullYear() == currentDate.getFullYear() && currentDate.getSeconds() == snapDay.getSeconds() && currentDate.getMilliseconds() == snapDay.getMilliseconds()){
    final.hidden = true
    end.hidden = false
    clearInterval(it)
  }
  theMonth = currentDate.getMonth()
  if(theMonth == 10){
    month.innerHTML = "3"
  }else if(theMonth == 11){
    month.innerHTML = "2"
  }else if(theMonth == 12){
    month.innerHTML = "1"
  }
  year.innerHTML = snapDay.getFullYear() - currentDate.getFullYear()
  days.innerHTML = currentDate.getDate() - snapDay.getDate()
  minutes.innerHTML = currentDate.getMinutes() - snapDay.getMinutes()
  seconds.innerHTML = currentDate.getSeconds() - snapDay.getSeconds()
  milli.innerHTML = currentDate.getMilliseconds() - snapDay.getMilliseconds()
},01)
```

Comment: Your variables should all be declared with `var`

Comment: Also you probably want to initialize `currentDate` **inside** the timer function, otherwise it will never change.

Comment: @Pointy I've created other javascript programs with using var to declare variables and the programs work fine.

Comment: :faceplam: @Pointy Thank you, that was the error.

Comment: Well the issue is that not using `var` means that you're making **global** variables, and that can cause some very weird issues in browser JavaScript because global variables are properties of the `window` object.  Seriously, my strong advice is to get used to declaring with `var` (or `let` or `const`, as appropriate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after @Pointy helped me I figured out that the error was that I was declaring the date() outside the setInterval and it wasn't a setInterval problem.